# Change Today Date in kendoDatepicker

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui

is it possible to change highlighted today date in `kendodatepicker`.

I have tried this.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(29);
```

But the bottom of the calendar still shows Today Date.

Comment: Changing the date of a variable doesn't affect the kendo date picker. Could you please provide the full code?

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker/configuration/footer *However*, this will not change the behavior of the "today" button.

Answer (score 0):

Add value tag in input and try`value="29/02/2020"`

Comment: Sorry Dhaval_512, Same result as before.